# Problem with starting ActiveMQ 5.4.1

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am developing a web application that will use ActiveMQ. I downloaded the Unix version from website and ran on my Mac.

It was working fine(I can oen the web console and configure the queues stuff) until I ran the helloworld code. After running the code, I can't open the web console and can't start ActiveMQ from terminal as well.

If anyone could hele me out, it will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What helloworld code did you run? Are there any errors in the activemq.log file? Bruce

Comment: I think I have found the problem with lacking installing Spring.. Thanks for your reply.